# VLC Compile in android

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation, vlc

I compile vlc in *.apk.
Errors in Eclipse does not show, but when I run on the emulator goes to log the exception. The player does not start.

03-10 21:38:08.999: E / VLC / LibVLC (26114): Can't load vlcjni ​​library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libvlcjni: findLibrary returned zero

Compile on Ubuntu.
sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

From just that error, you actually haven't actually compiled the .so files so there is no libvlcjni. So either you have just compiled the Java end of the VLC player or your Java Code or jni/ setup is not correct.